# calculating a limit of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How can I calculate $$\lim_{n\to \infty} e^n\left(1 + \frac 1n\right)^{-n^2}$$

I've tried by switching the part with $e^n$ to $(1+1/n)^n$ but then I got 1 and it doesn't make sense. I'll glad for help!

Comment: because e^n = (1+1/n)^n , and all that in the power of n. therefore it's (1+1/n)^(n^2)

Comment: @R-Y If you want to substitute $e^n$ with one of its limit formulations, you should use $e^n=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1k\right)^{nk}$ or $e^n=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1+\frac nk\right)^{k}$. Not that it works, but at least we write the correct thing.

Comment: @R-Y Why would $e^n = (1+1/n)^n$ be true?!

Comment: I tried use it by the regular form of e,

Comment: anyway, I'll glad to know hoe can it be solved

Comment: To be explicit, the correct thing to write would $$\lim_{n \to \infty} e^n \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{k \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)^{nk} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n^2}.$$
What you have written is not correct. $e^n \neq (1 + 1/n)^n$.

Comment: and how can we continue from here , with n and k ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I got it...

First, write
$$
e^n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n^2} = e^n e^{\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n^2}\right)} =e^{n-n^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}
$$

Now, since $e^{[\bullet]}$ is continuous, we have:
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^{n-n^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)} = e^{\left[\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\left(n-n^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)}\right]}
$$
Thus, we turn our attention to $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\left(n-n^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)}$. Let $\epsilon = 1/n$, hence we can write:
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\left(n-n^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)} = \lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon} - \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\left(\ln(1+\epsilon)\right)\right)
$$
Now, recall that the Taylor series for $\ln(1+\epsilon)$ around the origin looks like
$$
\ln(1+\epsilon) = \epsilon-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}+\frac{\epsilon^3}{3}-\frac{\epsilon^4}{4}+\cdots
$$
Hence,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} - \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\ln(1+\epsilon)\right) &= \lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} - \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\left(\epsilon-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}+\frac{\epsilon^3}{3}-\frac{\epsilon^4}{4}+\cdots\right)\right)\\&=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon} - \frac{1}{\epsilon}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon^2}{4}-\cdots\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\left(n-n^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)} = \frac{1}{2}$ and thus
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n^2} = e^{1/2} = \sqrt{e}
$$